$f'(2)$ for $f(x)=\frac1{x-2}$ using the Limit Definition
Question: Is this algebraic solution correct?
Right-Hand Derivative Calculation
$f(x) = \frac{1}{x - 2}$ 
$f'_{+}(2) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(2 + h) - f(2)}{h}$ 
$f(2 + h) = \frac{1}{h}$ 
$f'_{+}(2) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{1}{h} - \text{undefined}}{h}$ 
$f'_{+}(2) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{1}{h}}{h}$ 
$f'_{+}(2) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{1}{h^2}$ 
$f'_{+}(2) = \infty$
Left-Hand Derivative Calculation
$f(x) = \frac{1}{x - 2}$ 
$f'_{-}(2) = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(2 - h) - f(2)}{-h}$ 
$f(2 - h) = \frac{1}{-h}$ 
$f'_{-}(2) = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{\frac{1}{-h}}{-h}$ 
$f'_{-}(2) = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{1}{h^2}$ 
$f'_{-}(2) = \infty$
Question 2: Is it alright to say that we can ignore Undefined Points? We ignore undefined values at specific points if they do not influence the overall trend or behavior of the function as we approach that point. Even though $(2)$ is undefined at $ℎ=0$, as long as
$(2)$ does not actually depend on $ℎ$, treating it as a constant and focusing on how
$(2)$/$ℎ$ behaves as $ℎ$ approaches 0 is valid for finding the limit.
The undefined nature at a specific point $ℎ=0$ does not change the limit calculation if $(2)$ is considered constant in the limit process.

You can't treat undefined as a constant. Here is way: Suppose you could. Then $1=\lim_{x\to0}((1/x+1)-1/x)=\lim_{x\to0}(1/x+1)-\lim_{x\to0}(1/x)=undefined-undefined=0$

Could you provide more information like, where does the question come from and what is your motivation for asking this?

I would like to math vlog about the derivative of 1/x-2 using the Limit Definition. Hope this is ok with you.

Something undefined does not exist. You cannot do anything (add, multiply, subtract, etc) with it. Using an expression with an undefined element is a no-no

A necessary condition for the derivative of a function $f$ to exist at point $a$ is that $f$ is continuous at $a$. The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}$ is discontinuous at $2$. Indeed, $f(2)$ is not even defined. This implies that the derivative $f'(2)$ doesn't exist.
In your evaluation, you treated "undefined" as zero. Do not do this, ever. If you are trying to evaluate something, and partway through that calculation you find that something is undefined, that's a pretty good sign that the thing you're trying to evaluate is also undefined.

I agree. Thank you.

Another way is to "evualate" the limit and show that it doesn't exist at $x=2$.
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{x-2+h}-\frac{1}{x-2}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\cdot\frac{x-2-x+2-h}{(x-2)(x-2+h)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-1}{(x-2)(x-2+h)}$$ which is equal to $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{(x-2)^2}$, which is undefined at $x=2$. So $f'(2)$ doesn't exist.

I appreciate this idea. Since f(2) does not exist, we should avoid using the limit definition that includes it as a term. Splendid!

However, I would like to compute the right-hand derivative and the left-hand derivative. The limit definitions for these tasks involve the term f(2).

Inituitively, the right hand derivative is $+\infty$, and the left hand is $-\infty$. However calculating the limit is not possible, because $f(2)$ is not defined. But you can use the definition of limit or derivative to prove the right hand and left hand derivative.

Yes, I would suggest "since right-hand derivative is greater than 0, left-hand derivative is lesser than 0, so they are not equal, thus $f'(2)$ doesn't exist."

Since both the right hand and left hand derivatives are infinity, the function is not differentiable at x = 2. Differentiability requires finite, equal limits from both sides; unbounded behavior indicates a discontinuity or asymptote.

that also sounds right
